# Is it possible to get a reference to a variable in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, variables, reference

Is it possible to get a reference to a variable in Kotlin?

Example:

var vIndex = 0

::vIndex

Not supported [Variable references are not yet supported]

Can this be bypassed somehow?

Comment: What is your broader use case for trying to do so? Can you share the code showing what you're trying to do with this reference?

Comment: Variable references need to be added to the named list once so that you can easily retrieve their values in different parts of the function by name.

"VariableName" -> ::Variable -> Value

Comment: https://codeshare.io/xv6RzP

Comment: But why not just use the variables? Why do you need references? And why do you want to access variables by name in an unsafe way, while the language allows you to use variables directly in a type-safe way? How do you want to use the structure you're building?

Comment: If I remove references in the C# code, then the value of the variables is always zero. The value that they received during initialization. I need the values of the variables in each line of code. How they change.

Comment: It would be nice if you provided more code in the question to explain the intended behaviour of the overall piece of code that you shared here. Variables holding objects (*reference variables*) in Kotlin are "pointers" already in a way, so if you create objects you will not need variable references. I have a feeling that you're working around a problem that could be solved with a simple class, but I'm not sure what structure you're trying to build nor how you want to use it so it's hard to help at the moment

Comment: The procedure l(_V) simply displays the values of the variables in the log.

            for (int vIndex = 0; vIndex < varList.Count; vIndex++)
            {
                data = data + varList[vIndex].Name + ":" + *varList[vIndex].Value + Environment.NewLine;
            }

Answer (score 1):

Rather than writing:

```
var vIndex = 0
val propertyReference = ::vIndex // error
```

You can put the local property into an anonymous object:

```
val foo = object {
    var vIndex = 0
    // you can also put other local properties that you want to reference here
    // in the same object, provided that they are in the same scope
}
val propertyReference = foo::vIndex
```

`propertyReference` here will be of type `KMutableProperty0<Int>`, just as you would expect. You can access/mutate `foo.vIndex` the same way you can the local property `vIndex`.

Of course, this has the additional overhead of creating an additional class file for the anonymous object, but alas, a workaround is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in your question, (local) variable references are not yet supported. But you can have a reference to a property, i.e. you can write:

```
class VariableReferences {

    var vIndex = 0

    var ref = ::vIndex
}
```